# how to write onChange in this script??can anyone tell me the correct syntax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

how to write onChange in this script??can anyone  tell me the correct  syntax?
I want to add these phpcode to my script 
Javascript code:

```
ih+='<div class="form-group drop_bottom" id="select_one_'+extra_num+'"><select  name="sizes_'+extra_num+'"  style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;width:200px; height:25px;line-height:20px;margin:0;padding:0;" id="sizes_'+extra_num+'" onChange="+document.getElementById("displayValue").value=this.options[this.selectedIndex].text;+document.getElementById("sizes_'+extra_num+'").value=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;this_total(this,1);grand_total(this)"><option value="0">Select One</option>
```

here is the php code:

```
   <div  style="position:relative;width:200px;height:25px;border:0;padding:0;margin:0;" id="select_one_0" class="form-group drop_bottom">

    <select name="sizes_0" id="sizes_0" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;width:200px; height:25px;line-height:20px;margin:0;padding:0;" onChange="document.getElementById('displayValue').value=this.options[this.selectedIndex].text; document.getElementById('select_sizes_0').value=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;this_total(this,1);grand_total(this)" >      <option value="0" >Select One</option>
            <?php
    $get_banner_tyes = Get_banner_tyes();
            if($get_banner_tyes != false)
             { while($row_get_banner_tyes = mysql_fetch_array($get_banner_tyes))
                 {
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row_get_banner_tyes['banner_type_value'] * $_SESSION['secondary_currency_value']; ?>_<?php echo $row_get_banner_tyes['banner_type_id']; ?>"><?php echo $row_get_banner_tyes['banner_type_name']; ?></option>

            <?php } ?>
                 <?php   }
            ?>         

                    </select>
    <input name="displayValue" placeholder="Width*Height value"   id="displayValue" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;width:183px;width:180px\9;#width:180px;height:23px; height:21px\9;#height:18px;border:1px solid #556;" onFocus="this.select()" type="text">
 <input name="idValue" id="select_sizes_0" type="hidden" >
      <input type="hidden" name="select_sizes_0" id="select_sizes_0">
     <input type="hidden" name="select_elements_0" id="select_elements_0"></div>
```

Comment: You should write function to follow best practices. and call that function.

Comment: onchange function not getting in this script. I think my syntax is not correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use single quote instead of double quote and add backslash before the quotes.

```
onChange="(document.getElementById(\'displayValue\').value=this.options[this.selectedIndex].text; document.getElementById(\'sizes_'+extra_num+'\').value=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;this_total(this,1);grand_total(this);)"
```